# Show block above another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now I have a timer block only above USER 1, how can I display the timer block only above USER 2?

There was a logic to create as many <th> as users, and then add the Timer component to the required <th>, but I can’t figure out how to select the specific <th> in which you need to add Timer

```
 
return (
<div className="container">
        <table className="table">
          <thead className="move">
            <th>MOVE</th>
            {
              [...Array(1)].map((index) => (
                <th key={index}>
                  <Timer minutes={minutes} seconds={seconds} />
                </th>
              ))
            }
          </thead>
          <thead className="thead">
            <th className="main">PARAMETERS REQUIREMENTS</th>

            {users.map((user) => (
              <th className="trade_user" key={user.id}>
                {user.name}
              </th>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td className="main">
                Availability of a set of measures that raise quality standards
                manufacturing
              </td>
              {users.map((user) => (
                <td className="trade_user" key={user.id}>
                  {user.complexesOfMeasures}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="main"> Lot production time, days</td>
              {users.map((user) => (
                <td className="trade_user" key={user.id}>
                  {user.productionPeriod}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="main">Warranty obligations, months</td>
              {users.map((user) => (
                <td className="trade_user" key={user.id}>
                  {user.warranty}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="main">Terms of payment</td>
              {users.map((user) => (
                <td className="trade_user" key={user.id}>
                  {user.paymentTerms}%
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="main">The cost of manufacturing a lot</td>
              {users.map((user) => (
                <td className="trade_user cost" key={user.id}>
                  {user.cost}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className="main">Actions:</td>
              {users.map((user) => (
                <td className="trade_user" key={user.id}>
                  {user.action}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
)
```

Component Timer

```
import React from "react";
import { CgSandClock } from "react-icons/cg";

export const Timer = ({ minutes, seconds }) => {
  return (
    <div className="move_time">
      <span>{minutes}</span>
      <span>:</span>
      <span>{seconds}</span>
      <div>
        <CgSandClock size="1.5em" className="move_item_clock" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` over the users to create the `<th>` elements as well.

```
<thead className="move">
{users.map(user => <th key={user.id}>{user.id===2?<Timer minutes={minutes} seconds={seconds}/>:"MOVE"}</th>)}
</thead>
```